# Is vigenary a real word?

Tags: meaning, numbers, latin, ordinal-numbers, obscure-terms

I was interested in determining words to describe ordinal *Latinate* series numbering above orders of 10 (i.e., "denary").

I found "duodenary", which makes sense based on the latin root *duodecim*, meaning 'twelve.' (see also etymology of the duodenum of the small intestine -- *duodeni*, meaning 'in twelves.').

However, I found no evidence of other ordinal numbering adjectives other than that for 20.

I have two questions:

1. [Here](http://www.english-for-students.com/Primary-1.html), [here](http://international-dictionary.com/definitions/?english_word=vigenary) and [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vigenary) suggest that "**vigenary**" is the Latinate ordinal term for "twentieth" (or "of the twentieth order"). However, none of these sources come across as legitimate. Can anyone confirm for me (through a more trustworthy and proper source) that "vigenary" is in fact the proper word to use here?
2. Do other Latinate ordinal adjectives (for orders > 10) exist?

Comment: There is *sexagesimal* - base 60

Comment: Well, OED does have *vigenary* as a headword. But it hasn't been updated since 1917, and it was marked as "rare" then.

Comment: @Mick: "Undenary" for 11, huh? This contradicts all other sources I've seen saying that 11 doesn't have a Latinate series term. Can you find any other sources for that word?

Comment: @theforestecologist I'm not supporting it. I just pointed it out. The author gives his source.

Comment: @Mick I am afraid you are confusing the numbers used for **order of levels** (primary, secondary, tertiary…) with those used for **bases of numeral systems** (unary, binary, ternary…).

Comment: Though [the source](http://the-difference-between.com/denary/vigenary) is not at all reputable, I figured I'd just share that at least someone came up with words for the missing numbers: "undenary (11) * duodenary (12) * tredenary (13) * quattuordenary (14) * quindenary (15) * sedenary (16) * septendenary (17) * octodenary (18) * novemdenary (19) " .... looks like they used [wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vigenary) as a source for some of these words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Vigenary*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/223320?redirectedFrom=vigenary#eid) is marked by the OED as rare, but the alternative ***vicenary*** is not so marked.

> **Vicenary**  ... adj.    ‘Belonging to twenty’ (Bailey, 1727); based on the number twenty. Cf. vigenary adj.
>
> - a1831  G. Peacock Arithm. in Encycl. Metrop. (1845) I. 371/1   Such a practice would naturally lead to the formation of a vicenary scale of numeration.
> - 1834   Penny Cycl. II. 337/2   In France the scale from 60 to 100 is strictly vicenary (by twenties).

The root of both 'vigenary' and 'vicenary' is from Latin *vīcēnārius*, in turn from *vīcēnī*, the [distributive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/distributive_number) form of *[vīgintī](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/viginti#Latin)* ('twenty').

Answer (score 2):

Probably not. *[Vigesimal](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vigesimal)* is a word, but the series *primary, secondary, tertiary…* seems to cover only numbers from 1 to 10 and 12:

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/what-comes-after-primary-secondary-tertiary

Comment: Support for the first ten + 12, but it didn't actually say they're aren't more for higher numbers...

Comment: I believe that is implied by omission.